# Is there any email client that would allow different sender address for each email?

Tags: software-recommendation, email-client

I would like to have an email client that would allow me to type a different sender address for each email.

The reason is that I have a spam filtering system in which I give a different email address to every service that I use and they are all forwarded to my mailbox. If one of the emails is leaked to spammers, I can see where it leaked.

The downside is that sometimes I need to reply to those emails and in order to avoid revealing my real email address, I need to set up a new mail account in evolution for each alias address.

When I was using Windows, I used an email client called The Bat!, which allowed me to just type the sender address each time instead of having to select from a drop-down list. Is there any email client with the same feature for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

## Using Identities in Thunderbird

Thunderbird offers the option to configure Identities for a single account.

Therefor:

- Open *Account Settings*
- Choose your account (click address in sidebar)
- Click the *Manage Identities* button
- Configure your identities in the new window

Those identities can later be selected from a dropdown while writing a mail.

Comment: That's a little better, but still you need to create all identities separately. I'm looking for an option that lets the user type anything they want as the sender address.